# How to customize selected RowPresenter for Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv, browsefragment

I want to increase size of selected `RowPresenter` and put a white border around it in `BrowseFragment`. I tried following to put border but its edge are fitting my card as I am using rounded corner for my cards.

```
private final class ItemViewSelectedListener implements OnItemViewSelectedListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item,
                               RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {
                ImageCardView cardView = (ImageCardView) itemViewHolder.view;
                GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
                border.setStroke(10, ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white));
                cardView.getMainImageView().setImageDrawable(border);
  }
}
```

Below is code how I am making my card's corner rounded:

```
<dimen name="lb_rounded_rect_corner_radius">10dp</dimen>
```

1. How can I increase size of selected card more than default zooming size?
2. How can I put white border around my selected card, so that it covers all edges smoothly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. How can I increase size of selected card more than default zooming size?

You can do this by passing in a larger FocusHighlight zoom factor when initializing your `ListRowPresenter`. You can initialize your presenter with the `FocusHighlight#ZOOM_FACTOR_LARGE` for the larger focused cards. `ListRowPresenter` has [this constructor](https://github.com/kingargyle/adt-leanback-support/blob/master/leanback-v17/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ListRowPresenter.java#L112).

> 2. How can I put white border around my selected card, so that it covers all edges smoothly?

You can provide your own subclass of `BaseCardView` (or `ImageCardView`) where you supply your own layout. When you have your own layout, you won't have any limiting factors. If you look at [this folder](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/tree/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/cards) in the leanback-showcase sample app, there are many examples of custom cards.

This covers a very simple example

```
public class YourCardView extends BaseCardView {

    public YourCardView(Context context) {
        super(context, null, R.style.TextCardStyle);
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_card_xml, this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

Where you supply your own xml file instead of `R.layout.your_card_xml`. There you can add borders and whatever else you'd like.